Can someone explain why this refrigerator exploded?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNk3RbIneqI
After seeing this article, I've been doing my research and found out this is a very rare case but possible.
Someone says the refrigerant, R600A, the other name of isobutane (I heard some uses mixture of isobutane and cyclopropane) is only 50 g to 100 g which is not enough to cause explosion. The components are strong enough to withstand the pressure. Even if a leakage happens, the gas:oxygen ratio is too low or high, so no worry about the explosion... Seems to make sense.
But in reality, it exploded.
There are several cases, although they're rare, and it seems no one was able to explain why/how these are happening (or simply I couldn't find one?).
Currently, I'm planning to place a 85 litre refrigerator in my dormroom, and I want to know how much should I be worried and what can I do to prevent any accident. If the small refrigerator explodes, would I be severely injured or burned? What can I do to prevent it?
Thanks in advance.

Best guess is that the cold plate inside the freezer or fridge gave up under very high pressure. The pressure cutout can be as high as 600 psi with some refrigerants. On a plate-type condenser, that can make quite a balloon bang.

a failure in the automatic defrost control could start the problem.

You looked for one reason? There may be many possibilities, perhaps the manufacturer is looking...

The refrigerant is flammable, and heavier than air. A refrigerant leak would sink to and follow the floor until it found an ignition source like a pilot light. On its way it would blend with air and form an explosive mixture, which would then blow up the kitchen when lit by the pilot light.
It might also be possible to set it off with the contacts inside the thermostat switch of the refrigerator itself.
In Oregon, pot farmers used butane to extract the THC content of their weed and concentrate it for use in vape pens and the like. It would sink to the bottom of the basement room in which they ran their blowdown extractions, find the pilot light for the water heater in the corner, and blow the pot farmers to kingdom come on an almost monthly basis.
Now that pot is no longer illegal here, the big money has gone into supercritical CO2 extraction factories which do not blow up.

Wow!  Some sad articles I found on this Oregon THC farmer topic, indeed a couple times a year, surprisingly even in 2024 (9 years after legalization): https://www.google.com/search?q=oregon+thc+butane+explosion
